# Zoom & Brush in Stacked Area Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, brush, stacked-chart

Playing with Mike's [Zoom & Brush](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172). How to change this when my area is stacked? In this case I use layer function

```
var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
  .data(stack(values))
  .enter().append("g").append("path")
    .attr("class", "layer")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .style("fill", (d,i) => d3.color(colors[i]))
    .attr("d", area);
```

But how redraw chart after zoom? What instead

```
focus.append("path")
  .datum(values)
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", area);
```

and

```
focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
```

?